# How to generate script code in java?

Tags: java, template-engine

What is a good way to generate code from Java?

I have a visual `FlowChart` app, and want to integrate some code generation for specific graphs.
So, I have mostly some objects (with names) and some connections between them (conditions).

I want these visual representation to transform in a specific type of scripting language.

Is there anything in java so that I can somehow define a template to generate my script?
Eg tell the template what properties to take from the visual objects, and how to arrange them in the output language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [Apache Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/index.html):

> The Apache Velocity Engine is a free open-source templating engine.

There is a comparison between FreeMarker and Velocity [here](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/fmVsVel.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try to use template engine like [FreeMarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/), you can generate any thing what you want.